# What is a term for sarcastically downplaying something?

Tags: word-usage, connotation

I remember reading the term for it years ago, but I can no longer remember what it is.

It is when someone downplays a situation, usually sarcastically.  They are fully aware of the problems of the situation, and are not downplaying it to hide something, but more or less to be snarky.

Examples:

> I was a bit concerned when I saw the bombs falling towards my head.
>
> Getting shot in the stomach ruined my day.
>
> Violent murder is typically frowned upon in polite society.

Comment: Outside of plain old *understatement*? Maybe *litotes* or *meosis*?

Comment: Understatement...

Comment: @DanBron Litotes! That's the word I was looking for in answer to this question. However, apparently that's not correct. Meiosis is, though.

Comment: _Minimisation_ perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Also found this one:
[Downplayers:](http://www.neo-philosophy.com/LogicWeek5.html)

Words and devices that make someone or something seem less significant than it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think all three, especially the first two would qualify as "[gallows humor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Death-related+humor)":

humor that treats serious, frightening, or painful subject matter in a light or satirical way.

Answer (score -1):

[Mock](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mock)

to laugh at or make fun of (someone or something) especially by copying an action or a way of behaving or speaking